# Tool for request/response visualization

Tags: uml

I'm designing some client-server web project with a lot of requests and responses.
So my question is what tool can I use to visualize my request/response map (like UML editors for code designing).

Comment: mind-mapping sw like freemind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in UML, Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems has facilities for "Web Modeling", where you model things like pages, servers, forms, etc.

It also supports WSDL 1.1, with forward and reverse engineering, although I haven't tested this myself.